# How do I convert the date/time of an event into a variable that I can use?

Tags: php, timestamp

This code works, with one exception. I am importing the dates of performances from a calendar. When the code grabs the next performance date, I want it to read whether it starts before 6PM or after.  If before, I want it to say "Today" and if it is after, I want it to say "Tonight."  I have tried using $dateEvent("H"), but it says I'm calling a function.  How do I convert the date of the event into a variable that I can use?

```
function calendar_dates() {  
    $servername = "localhost";  
    $username = "angelsdb";  
    $password = "R#start2013";  
    $dbname = "angelsice";  
    $fromToday = date("Y-m-d");

    /// Create connection  
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  
    // Check connection  
    if ($conn->connect_error) {  
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);  
    }  

    $sql = "SELECT event_start_date, recurrence_interval, event_name, post_content, event_start_time, event_slug, event_all_day FROM wp_em_events";  
    $result = $conn->query($sql);  

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
        // output data of each row  
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
            $fromCalendar = $row["event_start_date"];  
            $dateEvent = new DateTime($fromCalendar);  
            $dateToday = new DateTime($fromToday);  
            if(strtotime($fromToday) <= strtotime($fromCalendar) && $row["recurrence_interval"] < 1){   
                if($dateToday == $dateEvent) {  

                /// THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO TEST IF IT IS BEFORE 6PM OR AFTER USING THE VARIABLE $GREETING

                $time = new DateTime($row["event_start_time"]);  
                echo "<h2>" . $greeting . " @ " . $time->format('h:i a') . "</h2>";  
                echo "<a href='../events/". $row['event_slug'] . "'><h1>" . $row["event_name"] . "</h1></a>";  
                echo "<h3>" . $row["post_content"] . "</h3>";  

                } else {  

                $date = $dateEvent;  

                $time = new DateTime($row["event_start_time"]);  
                echo "<h2>" . $date->format('l') . " @ " . $time->format('h:i a') . "</h2>";  
                echo "<a href='../events/". $row['event_slug'] . "'><h1>" . $row["event_name"] . "</h1></a>";  
                echo "<h3>" . $row["post_content"] . "</h3>";  

                }  
                return;  
                }  
            }  
    } else {  
           echo "0 results";  
    }  

    mysqli_close($conn);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$dateEvent = "2011-07-26 20:05:00";//for example
$dateEvent = strtotime($dateEvent);
$time= date('H', $dateEvent);
if((int)$time>18)
    echo 'Tonight';
else 
    echo 'Today';
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/inySfy)

Comment: Nope.  Got this: <b>Warning</b>:  date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in <b>/home/rowlandwilliams/public_html/angels/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/functions.php</b> on line <b>99</b>

Comment: what is in $dateEvent?

Comment: $dateEvent is pulled from SQL, is the date a calendar event occurs.  Crap!  My mistake is that I'm pulling the date not the time.  Let me see if I can make this work.  The start time in my example is 23:00:00.  The one mistake I got so far is that it can't read colons.  I put it in quotes, but that doesn't seem to work.  Hold on.

Comment: Quick question about your example above: You set $dateEvent = date("h"...)  But the date I'm working with isn't the current date, but a date from the database.  How do I adjust for that?

Comment: It works!  This is the code that did it:

    $timeEvent = $row["event_start_time"];  
    if((int)$timeEvent<"18:00:00") {  
        $greeting = 'Today';  
    } else {   
        $greeting = 'Tonight';  
    }

Answer (score 0):

Compare the date to a `DateTime` at 6pm see the [ideone](http://ideone.com/KsbAFK)

```
<?php

// your code goes here

$t1 = new DateTime("4:30pm");
$t2 = new DateTime("8:30pm");


function todayTonight($t) {
    return (new DateTime("6:00pm") < $t) ? "Tonight" : "Today";
}

echo todayTonight($t1) . "\n";
echo todayTonight($t2) . "\n";
```